# AJAX is not triggering PHP mailer when submitting from iOS

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mailer

```
dataString = 'param=stuff';
jQuery.ajax({
   cache: false,
   type: "POST",
   headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
   url: "https://example.com/assets/mailer.php",
   data: dataString, 
   success: window.location.href = "https://example.com/thankyou"
});
```

This works fine with various browsers on Windows, MacOS, and Android. On iOS, the PHP mailer script isn't triggered, but the redirect works. Using Safari dev tools I can see there aren't any errors in the console. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`success` accepts a function, you are passing it a string while simultaneously assigning that string to `window.location.href` and navigating away.

Use a function instead...

```js
jQuery
  .post("https://example.com/assets/mailer.php", { param: "stuff" })
  .done(() => {
    window.location.href = "https://example.com/thankyou";
  });
```

Note that I've removed all the redundant options you were setting and used the safer method of encoding the request body.

---

FYI you definitely [don't need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) for this

```js
fetch("https://example.com/assets/mailer.php", {
  method: "POST",
  body: new URLSearchParams({ param: "stuff" }),
}).then((res) => {
  if (res.ok) {
    window.location.href = "https://example.com/thankyou";
  }
});
```